# How to calculate the number of independent components/degrees of freedom for symmetric tensors?

Tags: tensor-calculus

I was studying about the cosmological perturbation theory and came across this:
***""Being symmetric, the two perturbed tensors contain ten
degrees of freedom each, describing different aspects of gravity.""***

Can someone explain what this means in simple terms?

Answer (score 2):

Let a set of complex numbers be represented by a mathematical quantity $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}$ with $p$ indices. These indices take values in the set $\left\lbrace 1,2,3, \cdots ,d-1,d \right\rbrace$. Here $p$ and $d$ are positive integers, so
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split} 
 T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}} \in \mathbb{C}\;, \qquad & i_{k}\in \left\lbrace 1,2,3, \cdots ,d-1,d \right\rbrace\\
  & p, d \in \mathbb{N}\boldsymbol{=}\left\lbrace 1,2,\cdots\right\rbrace
 \end{split} 
\tag{A-01}\label{A-01}  
\end{equation}
We call this quantity the *tensor*  $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}$. In general, tensors are quantities defined in spaces and behave by a specific way under transformations in these spaces. Here, the term tensor  is used to give a name and nothing more. Also, the integer $d$ is usually the dimension of a space.

The tensor $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}$ defined by equation \eqref{A-01} represents $d^{p}$ linearly independent elements.

Suppose now that, under the permutation of a pair of indices $\left( i_{r},i_{s}\right)$, the element remains unchanged
\begin{equation}
  T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{r}\cdots i_{s}\cdots i_{p}}\boldsymbol{=}T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{s}\cdots i_{r}\cdots i_{p}}
\tag{A-02}\label{A-02} 
\end{equation}
Then we say that the tensor $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{r}\cdots i_{s}\cdots i_{p}}$ is *symmetric with respect to the pair* $\left( i_{r},i_{s}\right)$. If equation \eqref{A-02} is valid for any pair $\left( i_{r},i_{s}\right)$ then we call the tensor $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}$ *symmetric with respect to the $p$ indices* or simply *symmetric*. The question is : how many are the linearly independent elements of a symmetric tensor $\;T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}\;$?

The number of linearly independent elements in case the tensor $T_{i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{p-1}i_{p}}$ is symmetric with respect to its $p$ indices is
\begin{equation}
N\left(p,d\right)\boldsymbol{=}\binom{p+d-1}{d-1}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\left(p+d-1\right)!}{p!\left(d-1\right)!}  
\tag{A-03}\label{A-03}  
\end{equation}

In the Figure below we see a set of 10 elements (10 degrees of freedom) of a symmetric tensor $\mathrm a_{ijk}$ with $p\boldsymbol{=}3$ indices and $d\boldsymbol{=}3$
\begin{equation}
N\left(3,3\right)\boldsymbol{=}\binom{3+3-1}{3-1}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{5!}{3!2!}\boldsymbol{=}10  
\tag{A-04}\label{A-04}  
\end{equation}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you're talking about a rank $2$ in $4$ dimensions. This means that, in principle, you have $4\times 4=16$ parameters to choose.

It's pretty easy to evaluate the real degrees of freedom, or free parameters, if you visualise the tensor, call it $A_{ij}$ as a matrix. Being symmetric means that $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$. This means that you have to choose only half of the parameters beside the ones on the diagonal since $A_{ii} = A_{ii}$ it's trivial. So $4$ diagonal elements, there remains $16-4=12$ parameters. You only have to choose half of them since the other half are the same with opposite sign, so $12/2 = 6$ parameters. So, the only degrees of freedom for a rank-$2$ tensor in $4$ dimensions is $6+4 = 10$.

Comment: There seems to be a little confusion in your answer, the matrix mentioned is symmetric, not antisymmetric. The diagonals aren't necessarily fixed to zero, which is what leads to the 10 independent components right? Otherwise it'd just be 6...

Comment: @Philip Ohw yes, I don't know how I made such a bad mistake, I'll correct it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about tensor of rank 2 in 4 dimensional spacetime. Such tensor has two indeces and there are 4 possibilities for each index. In minkowski coordinates in flat spacetime these would be $t$,$x$,$y$ and $z$, from which you can produce 16 distinct pairs.

When tensor is symmetric however the pair $\mu\nu$ is the same as pair $\nu\mu$. This reduces number of possibilities to 10. The reason is, that the original 16 combinations can be divided into two groups - 12 combinations where the two indeces are different from each other and 4 combinations where the two indeces are the same. From the first group only half is independent due to symmetry which reduces possible combinations to 6 and you need to add 4 remaining combinations from second group.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about any 4 by 4 matrix. It has 16 elements. But if it is symmetric then the ones in the top right triangle are the same as those in the bottom left triangle. Therefore as soon as the 6 in the top right, and the 4 along the diagonal, have been specified, you know the whole matrix. That's 6 + 4 = 10.

If the matrix were antisymetric then you would also know the diagonal elements to be zero so then there would be just 6 degrees of freedom.

If you want to go to $N$ dimensions rather than 4, then the more general answer for a symmetric second rank tensor is $_1 C _N + \, _2 C _N$. If you want to consider tensors of higher rank then try the answer here from Frobenius. The aim of my answer has been to get straight to the main point you need.